# Find Slope of Data in Sympy / Veusz

Tags: python, sympy, veusz

I'm using Veusz to Visualize some motion data consisting of a position and a millisecond timestamp.

I would like to calculate Velocity and Acceleration (which are simply 1st and 2nd derivatives of Position) but the use of the 'Diff()' function seems to be beyond my grasp at this time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Something like  `expr.diff(x, i)` means to differentiate expr with respect to x, i times. Hope this helps. It will be better if you could show some example code.

Comment: ok, so I went and tried to create a New Dataset:

In Value, I typed: `CommandPosition.diff(Milisecond, 1)`
CommandPosition = position values
Milisecond = time values
Both are 1D arrays with the same dimension (15342 items)
The Error Message comes out saying "Unsafe Expression. [...] Function has no identifier"

Comment: It will be great if you could edit your question and show some clear code examples.

Comment: I did some more reading and your comment helped a lot.  Is DIFF only applicable if I have an actual mathematical expression (ie: Ax^2+Bx+C) and not for actual numerical data sets?

What I currently have is timestamped physical data and not a motion equation.  Is there a function in SYMPY (and by extension, Veusz) that would let me do this analysis?

Comment: SymPy provides functions for symbolic manipulation. It's not much suited for playing with numerical data. Maybe some other library like scipy can help you with that. I am not familiar with veusz though.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using diff(Y)/diff(X)